# Google map api in my react app doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I'm going to use @react-google-maps/api@2.19.2 and I got the following error and I have no idea how to fix it. Please help me.

My code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const MapContainer = () => {
  const [selectedAddress, setSelectedAddress] = useState(null);

  const handleMapClick = (event) => {
    // Get the latitude and longitude of the clicked position
    const clickedLat = event.latLng.lat();
    const clickedLng = event.latLng.lng();

    // Call the Geocoding API to retrieve the address details
    const geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode(
      { location: { lat: clickedLat, lng: clickedLng } },
      (results, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
          if (results[0]) {
            // Extract the formatted address from the API response
            const address = results[0].formatted_address;

            // Update the selected address state
            setSelectedAddress(address);
          } else {
            console.log("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
      }
    );
  };

  const [mapLoaded, setMapLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places`;
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    script.onload = () => setMapLoaded(true);
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }}>
      {mapLoaded && (
        <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="MY_API_KEY">
          <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
            center={{ lat: 53.23, lng: 35.34 }}
            zoom={10}
            onClick={handleMapClick}
          >
            {selectedAddress && <Marker position={selectedAddress} />}
          </GoogleMap>
        </LoadScript>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapContainer;
```

My error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: h is undefined
    fda https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places:231
    promise callback*fda/< https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places:231
    setTimeout handler*fda https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places:231
    Load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places:14
    <anonymous> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places:388
    <anonymous> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places:388
```

I want to use the map so that the user can enter his address, but the map does not load.
I used the @react-google-maps/api package, but I encountered an error.

Comment: In the error message there are lots of "YOUR_API_KEY", and in your code too. Maybe you should look at Google Map's API v3, generate a key and use it in your code. Also, if you look at the package's page, in the first step after installation, they tell you how to add keys to your code : [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api)

Comment: I created my key and put it in it, but I still got the same error, that's why I put the general error here, and it's not about the key.

Comment: Where is that 'h' in your code? It looks like your error points to that as the cause by saying `h is undefined fda`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You have set a condition that cannot be met initially that blocks the `<LoadScript>` component

This prevents your map from rendering all together but first of all let's address the multiple issues within your code.

First is that you are loading the Maps Javascript `script` manually in your useEffect hook in here:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places`;
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;
  script.onload = () => setMapLoaded(true);
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  };
}, []);
```

This would not enable your map to load because the `react-google-maps/api` library is not designed this way. So I suggest you read the documentation more before trying out something for recommended ways of working on libraries. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

And then you are also using the built in `LoadScript` component from the `react-google-maps/api` library.

```
{mapLoaded && (
  <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="MY_API_KEY">
    <GoogleMap
      mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      center={{ lat: 53.23, lng: 35.34 }}
      zoom={10}
      onClick={handleMapClick}
    >
      {selectedAddress && <Marker position={selectedAddress} />}
    </GoogleMap>
  </LoadScript>
)}
```

As you can see in the above code, you have included a `mapLoaded` in the condition and after playing around with your code, this seems to be the one causing the issue because it prevents the `<LoadScript>` component from rendering all together.

I tried moving it after the `LoadScript` component and the map worked, but is showing that the Maps JS script has been loaded multiple times, so what I did is I just removed the useEffect hook that tries to load the script altogether and removed the `mapLoaded` condition and everything seems to be working fine.

So your code should look something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker } from "@react-google-maps/api";

const MapContainer = () => {
  const [selectedAddress, setSelectedAddress] = useState(null);

  const handleMapClick = (event) => {
    // Get the latitude and longitude of the clicked position
    const clickedLat = event.latLng.lat();
    const clickedLng = event.latLng.lng();

    // Call the Geocoding API to retrieve the address details
    const geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode(
      { location: { lat: clickedLat, lng: clickedLng } },
      (results, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
          if (results[0]) {
            // Extract the formatted address from the API response
            const address = results[0].formatted_address;

            // Update the selected address state
            setSelectedAddress(address);
          } else {
            console.log("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          console.log("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }}>
      {
        <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey="MY_API_KEY">
          <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
            center={{ lat: 53.23, lng: 35.34 }}
            zoom={10}
            onClick={handleMapClick}
          >
            {selectedAddress && <Marker position={selectedAddress} />}
          </GoogleMap>
        </LoadScript>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapContainer;
```

If you want to check it out yourself, here's a working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-a-map-t2tt6m?file=/src/Map.js

I hope this helps!